# Can NOT use KaiOS simulator

Tags: firefox-os, kaios

I installed Lubuntu in a VM and I have the KaiOS simulator running on it. My problem is that the menu is not visible on the screen of the emulated device.

Firefox OS emulator doesn't seem to work anymore, so this is the only option. I can not install the Firefox OS simulator in the WebIDE in any shape or form. The installer says that the addon is corrupt and the WebIDE doesn't even have an "**install simulator**" section anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needed to downgrade to Firefox 32 and now it works